# Decryption of incoming web push messages in .NET

Tags: c#, cryptography, web-push, telegram-api, wtelegramclient

According to this [Telegram link](https://core.telegram.org/api/push-updates), I generate a `p256dh` and `auth` and then register them with Telegram server using the code below:

```
var ecParameters = Org.BouncyCastle.Asn1.Nist.NistNamedCurves.GetByName("P-256");
var ecSpec = new ECDomainParameters(ecParameters.Curve, ecParameters.G, ecParameters.N, ecParameters.H, ecParameters.GetSeed());
var keyPairGenerator = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("ECDH");
keyPairGenerator.Init(new ECKeyGenerationParameters(ecSpec, new SecureRandom()));
var keyPair = keyPairGenerator.GenerateKeyPair();

var publicKey = ((ECPublicKeyParameters)keyPair.Public).Q.GetEncoded(false);
var privateKey = ((ECPrivateKeyParameters)keyPair.Private).D.ToByteArrayUnsigned();

var baseKey = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(publicKey);
var baseAuth = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode("rnd96257410358jh"u8.ToArray());

var token = $"{{\"endpoint\":\"https://my.endpoint.com/telegrampush\", \"keys\":{{\"p256dh\":\"{baseKey}\", \"auth\":\"{baseAuth}\"}}}}";
var tokenType = 10;
var sandbox = false;
var secret = ""u8.ToArray();
var result = await TelClient.Account_RegisterDevice(tokenType, token, sandbox, secret, []); // result is true which means success.
```

Then I receive the encrypted push messages at my endpoint URL (ASP.NET Core).

Here's an example of incoming messages:

Headers:

- Content-Type--["application/octet-stream"]
- Content-Length--["305"]
- Content-Encoding--["aesgcm"]
- Encryption--["salt=aQq1xjPD4RTD7UQ-xAwB7Q"]
- Crypto-Key--["dh=BOVgNTu5ncaG-eycXbmIVzNonV1uDYL0FG4cojjUm-j3Dg_u4Af-qLEDc4QRknBDxqeiNuqjVi8bzkWvkx14eaQ"]
- TTL--["2419200"]
- Urgency--["high"]

And body is some byte array.

I found [this MS link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesgcm), but I'm not sure how to use it!

Comment: With regard to the posted header data, this may be an encryption with AES/GCM, whereby the key is determined using ECDH (in conjunction with HKDF) with curve P-256. This assumption would also fit in with the section [*Notification encryption*](https://core.telegram.org/api/push-updates#notification-encryption) of your Telegram link, which in turn refers to [RFC 8291, Message Encryption for Web Push](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8291), where the protocol is described in detail. Your MS link only covers a fraction, namely the AES/GCM part.

Comment: For an implementation, you should first implement the asymmetric part, which includes the derivation of the key (and IV) via ECDH and HKDF. The derived data should then be used to decrypt the actual ciphertext using AES/GCM. If you get stuck, post your code, ideally with (non-production) test data.